# My Nodejs code point to Test database instead of my actual database in Mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My insert command is working properly, from Nodejs to Mongodb . But instead of inserting into my database "School" in my mongodb cluster, it inserts into "test". How to point the insertion to my database.

My connection url **format** is like below

```
DATABASE_URL =mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@cluster0.<7 letter word>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Is there anything i need to change?

My database connection code

```
//database
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewURLParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are connecting to the default db on the cluster, which is your case is probably test. You should specify the db you want to connect to
`your-connection-string/[defaultauthdb][?options]]`
Read more [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Comment: Everytime .. Some one Some where is helping me to code.. I am very grateful to the developers community.